# displaying trees on graphviz

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree

I was wondering how to display my python code onto a software called graphviz. I wanted to display a binary tree which looked like this on graphviz.

```
    1
   /  \
  29    4 
 /       \ 
25         2
         /
        5
```

This is the code I wrote to create the tree, I just want to know how to display this into graphviz using Dot Language.

```
def print_tree(tree):
    if tree is not None:
            print_tree(tree.get_left_subtree())
            print(tree.get_value())
            print_tree(tree.get_right_subtree())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dot is able to draw a graph just for edges. You can print all of your edges (it will depend of your tree implementation) and let dot do the rest.

Edit: A dot file is just like that

```
Graph {
    a -- b -- c;
    d -- e;
}
```

So you can use python to do:

```
print("Graph {")
for e in g.edges():
    print(e[0], " -- ", e[1])
print("}")
```

Comment: thing is I dont know how to put the python code into dot language ?

Comment: dot is really easy, it is just `Graph{ a--b; b--c; ...}. Use python to make the file and compile it with Graphviz.

Comment: ahh okay i get it. Thing is i saved my example.py file as example.gv to open it in graphviz but its giving me an error ? whys that

Comment: your exemple.py will output something that will be used by graphviz, so something more like `python exemple.py > out.dot | graphviz out.dot -Tsvg`

Comment: okay thanks! just currently changed the code but getting errors not sure aboout ill try figure it out :)